How to return number ranking based on criteria?
I've run into an issue that I can't quite figure out. I need to return the placement of a list of values based on a separate criteria.
I have a table that looks like this:

I'm looking for a way to fill in the place column automatically with a formula. Initially, this was going to be done in Excel, which I asked about earlier and received some great responses. Unfortunately, none of those responses will work in Sheets. I'm not as familiar with Sheets and what it can do and what formulas transfer.
A couple of things to keep in mind:

The likelihood of two totals being the same is practically 0%. The numbers I am giving are for demonstration purposes only. The actually values being used go out to 7 decimal places.
The formula can return either just the top 3 or all of the places. It doesn't really matter.
Most likely the genders will be stacked, but not necessarily.



You may try:
=rank(C2,filter(C:C,B:B=B2))



That seemed to work. Wow! That was way easier than some of the Excel formulas I tried.

For future reference: To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of manually having to type input data  from screenshots), the recommended method is to create a markdown table. You can use this tool to create the markdown_format & then add it to your question.
